# How to disable css3 transition mouseleave effect on cubic-bezier method?

Tags: animation, css, hover, transition, mouseleave

I have a CSS3 `rotate` `transform` with a `cubic-bezier` `transition-timing-function`, it is working fine on mouse over, but i want to disable the mouseleave animation. I prepared a simple [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nyMbm/3/) to show you.

```
img {
    transition : all 1s cubic-bezier(0.680,-0.550,0.265,1.550);
}

img:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you don't want it to transition back when you hover off? You can use an "infinite" (actually very large) [**`transition-delay`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transition-delay) (that's the second time value in the [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transition)) for that.

Like this:

## [*demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/nyMbm/5/)

**CSS**:

```
img {
    transition: 0s 99999s; /* transition when mouse leaves */
}
img:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);

    /* transition on mouseover */
    transition: 1s cubic-bezier(0.680,-0.550,0.265,1.550);
}
```

Note that this will make the image rotate only on first hover.

---

If you want to make it rotate for each hover, then you'll have to use [*keyframe animations*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes). Like this:

## [*demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/3804996)

**CSS** (no prefixes, you'll have to add them):

```
img:hover {
    animation: rot 1s cubic-bezier(0.680,-0.550,0.265,1.550);
}
@keyframes rot {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

---

Also, I noticed that you were writing the unprefixed property first - you should always put it last. Especially now, when the coming versions of IE, Firefox and Opera are unprefixing transitions.